# How can i correctly output XML-data with ExecuteXmlReader

Tags: sql, .net, xml

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 Application and i try to use the function `ExecuteXmlReader` from the `SQLCommand` class to get a XML-result. The query don't produce any error. The query ends with `FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, ROOT('root')`. But when i try this:

```vb
Dim XML As XElement = XElement.Load(query.ExecuteXmlReader)
XML.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Result.xml"))
```

i get this errormessage:

*The XmlReader must be on a node of type Element instead of a node of type None.* (english translation)

*Der XmlReader muss sich auf einem Knoten vom Typ 'Element' befinden, nicht auf einem Knoten vom Typ 'None'.* (german translation)

It is strange that the error occures at the line with `XElement.Load(query.ExecuteXmlReader)`. But the code runs further! It also saves xml-data to disk! how can this happen and how can i read out the xml-result without an error?

Comment: It would help if you translate the error message to English

Comment: I think the translation of the error in english is:

"The XmlReader must be on a node of type Element instead of a node of type None."

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with multiple FOR XML AUTO statements reading.
Problem was solved passing XmlReader to System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument:

```
 public static XDocument MultipleNodes(XmlReader reader, string RootName = "Root")
    {
        var doc = new XDocument(new XElement(RootName));

        var xn = new XPathDocument(reader).CreateNavigator();
        XPathNodeIterator iterator = xn.Select("/*");   // Level 1 multiple Elements
        foreach (XPathNavigator item in iterator)
        {
            doc.Root.Add(XElement.Load(item.ReadSubtree()));
        }

        return doc;
    }
```